# Angular proxy calls don't seem to be made

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm reworking an older repo that I created using Angular 8 in which I updated to Angular 10. I'm trying to proxy all `http://localhost:4200` calls to `http://localhost:3000`. This has been working before so I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing since the update.

Error
[image]

proxy.conf.json (at root)

```
{
  "*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

angular.json (at root)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "WMDashboard": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/WMDashboard",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/app/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "WMDashboard:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "WMDashboard:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "WMDashboard:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "WMDashboard:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "WMDashboard:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "WMDashboard"
}
```

package.json

`"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",`

Node server (server.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dashboardRouter = require('./routes/dashboardRouter');
const indexRouter = require('./routes');

app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at PORT:', port);
```

Router (dashboardRouter.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/user/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  // some logic
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I’d love to understand why you would want to do this..?

Comment: @MikeOne I believe when I created the project I was trying to circumvent the `No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource` CORS issue